# Find and remove fields with special characters in mongoDB?

Tags: regex, special-characters, mongodb-query

I stored regex patterns by mistake as field names in MongoDB. Now I want to remove them. According to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3229) issue discussion on mongoDB.org it should be possible to have any characters but "." and the field must not start with "$".

However when I try to find a field containing a regexp with "\" I can find it (by using an extra backslash to escape it in the string).

```
> db.test.find({"(slot(maskin\\w+?|machine\\w+?))":{$exists:true}}).count()
> 10975
```

but I can't remove it by using "$unset":

```
> db.texts.update({"(slot(maskin\\w+?|machine\\w+?))":{$exists:true}},{$unset:{"(slot(maskin\\w+?|machine\\w+?))":""}})
> WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Here is an example doc for trial:

```
doc = {"(slot(maskin\w+?|machine\w+?))":1, "text": "bla vla yle rodman slotmachine."}
```

Comment: did you mean this `"slot(maskin\\w+?|machine\\w+?)"` ?

Comment: i suggest you to replace `\w+` with `\w*` beacuse there isn't a word character next to the string `machine`

Comment: If I understand you right Avinash, I also want to match "slot machines", not only "slot machine" in this case.